# How can I get the value of non-aggregated column with an aggregated column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sample table:

```
ColA   ColB   ColC
CBCP    25    popx
ABC1    10    ppp1
ABC1    25    ppxx
CBCP    30    xm2x
```

from there I would like to get these columns

```
ColA   ColB   ColC
ABC1    25    ppxx
CBCP    30    xm2x
```

what I would want is to get the row with max ColB.. But I am getting an error when I try to include the ColC in my query:

```
select ColA, max(ColB), ColC
from tblCaseDev
where ColB > getdate() group by ColA
```

this is my error..

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tblCaseDev.ColC' is invalid in the
select list because it is not contained in either
an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

hope someone could help me.. thanks in advance..

Comment: The columns in your query are not the same as in your example table.  Can you please correct them?

Comment: hahaha sorry.. ill edit it.. thanks for noticing.. =)

Comment: What version of SQL Server ?

Comment: Try one the first two solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9544400/1394393) with a `GROUP BY CalA` clause added on to the inner query or CTE and an additional ID check in the `WHERE` of the outer query. (Sorry. Forgot to put the link in the first time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
CaseNo,Date,Remarks,

(SELECT max(cast(Date as datetime)) FROM tblCaseDev subc WHERE subc.CaseNo=c.CaseNo Group by c.CaseNo) AS MaxEntryDate

FROM tblCaseDev c 

order by CaseNo
```

Comment: do you got it brother?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `row_number()` window function:

```
select CaseNo, "Date", Remarks
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by caseno order by date desc) as seqnum
      from tblCaseDev t
      where date > getdate()
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

You can do this the old fashioned way if you don't have `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from tblCaseDev t join
     (select caseno, max(date) as maxdate
      from tblCaseDev 
      group by caseno
     ) tsum
     on t.caseno = tsum.caseno and t.date = tsum.maxdate
```

Comment: i got a new error.. it says.. Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an aggregate query first, then join the original table to the aggregate query.

Example:

```
SELECT
    A.CaseNo,
    A.Date,
    B.Remarks
FROM (
    SELECT
        CaseNo,
        MAX(Date)
    FROM tblCaseDev 
    WHERE Date > GetDate()
    GROUP BY CaseNo
) A 
JOIN tblCaseDev B
    ON A.CaseNo = B.CaseNo
    AND A.Date = B.Date
```

Comment: i am getting the Remarks for all.. this first 2 columns are repeating.. i should only get the Remarks for the line that corresponds to it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` which generates sequential number for every group `ColA` and ordered by `ColB` in descending.

```
SELECT     ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM 
          (
               SELECT    ColA, ColB, ColC,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColA 
                                           ORDER BY ColB DESC) rn
               FROM tablename
          ) x
WHERE     rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59aa5/1)

If you want to get multiple records which ties up in `ColB`, you may want to change it to `DENSE_RANK()`.

- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: i got a new error.. it says.. Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.